# ng-controller is not detected from the bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've been working with angular js, but apparently I don't know how to proper use the $compile thingy, I need to use the login controller which I define for the angular application but i need to use it in the HTML that the bootbox "dynamically" generates something like this

```
element = '<div ng-controller = "loginCtrl"><input type="text" ng-model="username"/>';
element += '<input type="text" ng-model="username"/><input type="button" ng-click =    "login()" ></div>'
botbox.dialog(element);
```

but then I kinda try to do this...

```
ng.tcts.directive('livesession_bootbox', function($compile){
element = '<div ng-controller = "loginCtrl"><input type="text" ng-model="username"/>';
element += '<input type="text" ng-model="username"/><input type="button" ng-click =    "login()" ></div>'
var definition = {
 template:element,
 restrict:'E',
 scope: 'true'
}

return definition;
});
```

The truth is that I have no idea of how to make this work....

Comment: Why don't you check the modal dialog service provided by http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/‎

Comment: don't you know a way of bind this html and make work the ng stuff